# Flag identical group of rows

Tags: duplication

I would need to find a way to identify lines that are the same.

The comparison must be made on the first 4 columns (A-B-C-D) If these are identical I would like to identify them by inserting 1 in column E and if they are different by inserting 0, as a byte flag.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: For query-writing questions, please follow the [advice about question contents](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Is this a database question or an Excel question?...if the former, what database system and version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On any modern DBMS with window functions you can just do

```
CASE WHEN
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Project, Activity, Ressource, Factor) > 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```